# Frontend:8080 submitting to Backend:80 breaks when I change Axios param

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm building an application mostly for learning Vue (Vue3).

The frontend on port 8080 uses Axios to submit to the backend on port 80.

Here's my `vue.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    host: 'myste.com',
    public: 'myste.com:8080',
    proxy: {
      "/fn/*": {
        target: "http://myste.com",
        // because changeOrigin is true, and port 80 is the default, I don't need to include it here.
        changeOrigin: true,
        pathRewrite: {
            '^/fn': ''
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The docs say to send data with the data property

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/user/12345',
  data: {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  }
});
```

So that's what I did in my Vue3 app

```
this.$http({
    method: 'post',
    url: e.target.action,
    data: {toEmail: document.querySelector('.toEmail').value}
});
```

This leads to the call to the correct url (`myste.com/handler.php`), modified as desired by `proxy` settings, but no data is sent with it. My backend reports that the first argument is missing.

If I change 'data' to params

```
this.$http({
    method: 'post',
    url: e.target.action,
    params: {toEmail: document.querySelector('.toEmail').value}
});
```

It submits all the data, but to the wrong url (`myste.com:8080/fn/handler.php?toEmail=...`).

I've changed back and forth several times, this one property is all I'm changing for this oddity to occur.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround [in a github discussion](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/97#issuecomment-356862309), that keeps things pretty simple and processes `data.` I'm still interested to know what the problem is here and how I can fix it.

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import router from './router'

import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'

axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    if (config.headers['Content-Type'] && config.headers['Content-Type'] === 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded') {
      config.transformRequest = (data) => {
        const str = [];
        Object.keys(data).forEach(key => str.push(`${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(data[key])}`));
        return str.join('&');
      };
    }

    return config;
  }, error => Promise.reject(error));
```

My call to `this.$http` now looks like this, adding the content-type.

```
    this.$http({
        method: 'post',
        url: e.target.action,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        data: {...}
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the proxy is behaving correctly

the `params` option sends the data as query params, which is why you'd see them in the url. If you're using `POST` method, `data` is usually what you'd use with it, since it sends it as a payload. This also assumes that you're sending json payload, and you may be expecting a form response, which would be handled differently.. But it's hard to tell what your php API is expecting.